# TeamViewer not showing RDP session if laptop lid is closed

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I make use of TeamViewer to logon to my laptop remotely, which is always on and plugged in (but with the lid closed).

I’m finding that if I have an RDP session open, it’ll either be frozen and unresponsive if it’s an existing session, or if I try a new RDP session it’ll just be a black window. To me, it’s like it’s not rendering new graphics for the RDP window as it’s determined it doesn’t need to because the lid is closed.

Is there a way around this, either via TeamViewer itself or somehow changing my laptop settings? Unfortunately I’m not able to TeamViewer directly to my RDP session machines

Answer (score 0):

If there is an active RDP (Windows Remote Desktop) session on the remote Computer with the RDP window (currently) being minimized, a black screen appears.

For a minimized RDP window the whole desktop is being minimized. Therefore, there is no possibility for TeamViewer to grab the screen of the remote computer.

https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/4773-why-do-i-only-see-a-black-screen-after-connection-establishment